# Script working fine on development server but not remote server

Tags: php, memory, profiling, hosting

Am having problems with my PHP/MySQL website. It is running fine on my development machine but on Godaddy it has started giving me problems. After running it multiple times I either error 500(Internal server error) or connection timed out. Am now convinced that its not the web host as files like sitemap.xml are loading very fast.

I attempted profiling it with the NuSphere profiler and the total time it takes to load the scripts is 143.0ms. Using the Zend Controller benchmark tool(without any performance-related components) I can make an average of 12 requests per sec on my local script. Using 
I get PHP function memory_get_usage I get 1340648

My questions are

1. What is the the allowable amount of time that a script should take to load
2. How can I know the CPU utilization of my scripts
3. How can I know the memory utilization of my scripts

I use windows with Zend CE. I have checked the error logs and nothing shows. I have googled but none of the solutions seem to work .

Answer (score 0):

If its timing out on the server it's more than likely because a link to a resource in your script is not pointing to the correct location.

Leading to a function call not working or other resource not being found.

Comment: Thx @as_bold_as_love . Is there any way to locate this script. Nothing is showing on error logs

Comment: Hi @user1180807. youll need to get a debugger or just test bits of your code to isolate the issue. you could also trying increasing the timout - set_time_limit(60);  It's also worth check your htaccess file for errors. Have a look at this article on htaccess issues: https://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/1903/Why+am+I+getting+a+500+Internal+Server+Error+message%3F